# Making An HTML element inside a D3-Tip Trigger Click Event

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I am trying to trigger a click event from a button inside my D3-tip element as so:

```
var tip = d3.tip()
        .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
        .html(function(d) {
            var html = "<div class='row text-center'><div class='col-md-4 no-gutters'>" +
                       "<button class='btnn btnn-purple pull-left textSmall' id='1'>1</button>" +
                       "</div><div class='col-md-4 no-gutters'>" +
                       "<button class='btnn btnn-yellow pull-left textSmall' id='2'>2</button>" +
                       "</div><div class='col-md-4 no-gutters'>" +
                       "<button class='btnn btnn-aqua pull-right textSmall' id='3'>3</button>"

            return html;
    });

$("#1").on('click', function() {
     d3.select("#node1").style("opacity", 0);
});
```

But the only element I actually click on is that with class `d3-tip` instead of any button. I've tried changing around z-indices, but that hasn't work.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks.

Edit: I have used Gerardo's solution below (not using D3-tip but rather designing my own) but I cannot get the positioning correct - for some reason my tooltip continually appears below the SVG, when I use `d3.event.pageX` to position the tooltip, or when I use `d.x` (node position) in my force layout.

Why is this happening?

Thanks.

Comment: could you put together an example JSFiddle we can play with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is relatively simple if you had your own tooltip code, as the example below shows. Having your own tooltip code gives you more flexibility and control. So, technically, this is **not an answer to your question** because it doesn't use "D3-Tip".

Click "run code snippet", and hover over the circle to show the tooltip. Clicking on button 1 generates an alert.

```js
var svg = d3.select("body")
 .append("svg")
 .attr("width", 300)
 .attr("height", 300);
 
var tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div") 
 .attr("class", "tooltip")    
 .style("opacity", 0);

var circle = svg.append("circle")
 .attr("cx", 150)
 .attr("cy", 150)
 .attr("r", 100)
 .attr("fill", "steelblue");
 
circle.on("mouseover", function(){
 tooltip.html("<button id='but1'>Button 1</button><button  id='but2'>Button 2</button>")
 .style('top', d3.event.pageY - 10 + 'px')
 .style('left', d3.event.pageX + 10 + 'px')
 .style("opacity", 1);
 d3.select("#but1").on("click", function(){ alert("button 1 clicked")});
});
```

```css
div.tooltip { 
    position: absolute;   
    text-align: left;   
   white-space: normal;     
    padding: 4px;    
    font-size: 14px;  
    background: tan; 
    border: 1px solid gray;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Its not the best idea to add 'raw' html though

Comment: Thanks for this, but I can't figure out how to position it above the node that triggers the tooltip. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: I don't use D3-Tip, so I can't say. In my example, it's done regarding the mouse coordinates, but you can do it with a mix of `this` and `offsetTop`/`offsetLeft`. But the real challenge is this: in my example, I didn't set the `mouseout` for the tooltip, so you can click it. But you have to make the tooltip disappear after leaving the element!

Comment: Thanks. I am avoiding using D3-tip, and rather using your way, but on my page when I try and trigger the tooltip appearing by clicking on a node it positions the tip at the bottom of the page rather than coordinates specified by the mouse event.

Comment: Oh, that's because in my tooltip the `div` has an position "absolute", defined in the CSS.

Comment: Wait to see if someone provides an answer with D3-tip, because in my way there is a catch-22, as I said above: I didn't code the "mouseout" because the tooltip has all the pointer-events (to get the click). If you set the mouseout in the same element that have the mouseover, the moment you hover over the tooltip it disappears (because you left that element). If you set the tooltip's "pointer-events" to none it doesn't disappear anymore when you hover over it, but then you don't get the click!

Comment: Yes I know, and then you change the left and top of the element to define where it appears. For some reason, (see edit) when I use your positioning it positions the tooltip far below the SVG. Why is that? I am using a force directed layout and trying to position the tooltip above the nodes. All I am looking for is when a node is clicked (rather than mouseovers), the tooltip appears, then I can click buttons inside of it.

Comment: Did you check "position: absolute" for the tooltip's class in the CSS?

Comment: Yes, I kept all of your CSS for the tooltip.

Comment: See the link here: https://s3.postimg.org/99toyjklf/Screen_Shot_2016_08_16_at_16_24_57.png I clicked on the large purple node in the middle, and using all of your code, it appeared in the bottom under the SVG element alltogether.

Comment: Where are you appending your SVG? In a specific div? In that case, in the  `var tooltip`, you have to select the same div, instead of body.